Is $L = \{\sigma_1 u \sigma_2 v \sigma_3 \mid (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3 \in \Sigma, u, v \in \Sigma^*, |u| = |v|) and ...$ regular
The question asks to determine if any of the following languages above $\Sigma=\left \{ 0,1 \right \}$ is regular.
The languages are:
$L_1=\left \{ \sigma_1u\sigma_2v\sigma_3:\begin{matrix} \sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_2\in\Sigma \ , \ u,v\in \Sigma^{*}\\ |u|=|v|\\ \sigma_1=\sigma_2 \ and \ \sigma_1\neq \sigma_3 \end{matrix} \right \}$
$L_2=\left \{ \sigma_1u\sigma_2v\sigma_3:\begin{matrix} \sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_2\in\Sigma \ , \ u,v\in \Sigma^{*}\\ |u|=|v|\\ \sigma_1=\sigma_2 \ xor \ \sigma_2\neq \sigma_3 \end{matrix} \right \}$
About $L_2$ :
The words belonging to $L_2$ are of the following form:
$\left \{ 0\Sigma^{n}0\Sigma^{n}0\ , 1\Sigma^{n}1\Sigma^{n}1\ ,\ 1\Sigma^{n}0\Sigma^{n}1\ ,\ 0\Sigma^{n}1\Sigma^{n}0 \right \}: n\geq 0$
It holds that $\forall w\in L_2 \ , \ |w|=2n+3 : n\in\mathbb{N} \cup\left \{ 0 \right \}$.
I use the answer @codeR gave me to this question and came with the follow automaton:

About $L_1$ :
The words belonging to $L_1$ are of the following form:
$\left \{0\Sigma^{n}0\Sigma^{n}1 \ , \ 1\Sigma^{n}1\Sigma^{n}0 \right \} : n\geq 0$
It holds that $\forall w\in L_1 \ , \ |w|=2n+3 : n\in\mathbb{N} \cup\left \{ 0 \right \}$.
I think that this language is not regular.
Intuitively, I need to ensure that $\sigma_1=\sigma_2 \ and \ \sigma_1\neq \sigma_3$ 
but $\sigma_2\in(0+1)^{2n+1}$ and I can't control it's value.
I also used the pumping lemma for regular languages for $w=1^{n+2}0^{n+1}\in L_1$ and it gave me that $L_1$ is not regular.
Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I can use the pumping lemma for regular languages for $w=1^{n+1}0^{n+1}1\in L_2$ and I will get in the same way that $L_2$ is not regular as well.
I would really like to get some opinion on what I wrote.

Do you mean $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3 \in \Sigma$ and $u, v \in \Sigma^*$ as before?

@codeR Yes. I edited the post.

Yes, you are correct. Given $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3 \in \Sigma$ and $u, v \in \Sigma^*$, $L_2$ can be expressed as $0(0+1)^{2n+1}0 + 1(0+1)^{2n+1}1$, which is of course regular.
On the other hand, $L_1$ can be proven to be non-regular using the Pumping lemma. Hint: All strings in $L_1$ are of odd length. Take a string of the form $\omega = 01^m01^m1$, which is in $L_1$. Now take any decomposition $w = xyz$. Depending on your choice of $y$, when $|y|$ is odd, we can construct an even-length string $\omega' = xy^iz$ for any even $i$, which of course is not in $L_1$. When $|y|$ is even, we can force (by pumping with $i$) the middle $0$ to be shifted (either left or right). Simply letting $i=0$ causes the conditions $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$ and $\sigma_1 \ne \sigma_3$ to be violated.

Thank you. I'm wondering, $w=1^{n+1}0^{n+1}1\in L_2$. If I use the Pumping lemma with $w$, will it not contradict that $L_2$ is regular ?

How? Be careful with $\forall$ and $\exists$ in the proof. It is better to play the pumping lemma proof as a two-player turn-based game.

I made one mistake in $L_1$ though. I am rectifying that.
